# Will changing hostname fix invalid sender domain without causing any other problems?

Tags: email, sendmail

I am running Centos 6.4 and have a hostname of web01.domain.com - the system runs PHP, SSH and FTP only with no POP or IMAP mail and just uses Sendmail.

When sending emails via PHP using Sendmail most of them work fine but some are refused due to an invalid sender domain:

```
May 29 14:13:01 web01 sendmail[3145]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mx01.kundenserver.de.,
version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=AES256-SHA, bits=256/256 $150], dsn=4.0.0,
stat=Deferred: 421 invalid sender domain 'web01.domain.com' (misconfigured dns?) 
http://postmaster.1and1.com/error-messages/#invalidsenderdomain
```

The link above mentions:

```
An A record or MX record must be assigned to your sender domain in accordance 
with RFC 2181.
```

My mail is hosted elsewhere so I don't really want to mess around with A records or MX records unless I have to so if I change my hostname to domain.com from web01.domain.com will this fix the issue and what other problems could it cause? If not, what do I need to change at my DNS provider to "fix" this?

Thanks

Comment: If you downvote please at least have the courtesy to explain why

Comment: A records do not a Mail server make. They just want to have some assurances that the server sending is run by competent admins, and it makes tracing down issues easier also, as servers with bad domains are often enough hijacked. BTW, I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create an A record for your server, then if you can, set up an RDNS entry. There's no reason to set up an MX record, unless you're expecting it to receive mail.

Comment: Thank you Nick - I have added an A record for web01 and will wait for it to propogate. Re the Reverse DNS, when I do a "host ip-address" or nslookup what should I see back for this to be correctly configured?

Comment: You would normally do a dig -x <your ip>, it depends on who assigned the IP address to your server, you can normally ask your hosting provider to set up an RDNS entry for your IP (I am assuming it is just for the single server). As for what you should get back, http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-test-or-check-reverse-dns/

Comment: It is currently pointing to my webhost and not directly to the server so it gives something like ipaddress.mywebhost.com - is that wrong? I will leave it for a few hours until it propogates but want to know if that is what I should expect to see

Comment: It should point to  web01.domain.com if at all possible. If not, it shouldn't be the end of the world..

Comment: Thanks Nick, that's great - will see happens later when DNS has updated

Comment: This worked, thanks - the client in question has now received emails from the system, thank you again

Comment: Glad to have helped!